# Is tautomerism in ketimines possible?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines, tautomer

In a reaction between an aliphatic primary amine and a ketone, I could expect a ketimine as a product or intermediate. My question regards tautomerization of this intermediate: has tautomerization between the two possible imine structures ever been observed, or is even possible? I tried to search imine tautomerism and transamination, but I can't find what I'm looking for. I imagine this would be a simple experiment to conduct, but I can't find anything in the literature on this.

[image: Proposed ketimine tautomerism]

Comment: Yes, this is common. One example is enzyme catalyzed transamination reactions that utilize pyridoxal phosphate as a cofactor.

Answer (score 3):

I found something very similar to what I sought in Dose, Nature **179**, 734 (1957) though it involves aldimines and a decarboxylation step. The author gives a very well explained mechanism for the process and reports varying transamination ratios of valine based on the substitution of the aldehyde. An example:

[image]